# Duality argument to get $L^\infty-L^2$ inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, heat-equation, kernels

In page 79 of Davies's book on Heat Kernels and spectral theory, the author proves that
$$\lVert e^{-Ht}f \rVert_2 \leq c_1t^{-\mu/ 4}\lVert f \rVert_1$$
where the norms are $L^p$ norms. He states

> by duality, it follows that
>   $$\lVert e^{-Ht}f \rVert_\infty \leq c_1t^{-\mu/ 4}\lVert f \rVert_2$$

Can someone explain what exactly this "duality" argument is? Above, $e^{-Ht}f$ we can take to be the solution of the heat equation with initial data $f$ (where $H$ is the Laplacian).

Comment: I do not think this is research level. However, I do think it would be useful to record a discussion of certain duality arguments, maybe over at StackExchange. See [Q1](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100905/duality-argument-in-pde) [Q2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361621/what-is-the-standard-duality-argument) [Q3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664035/whats-this-standard-duality-argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have shown that $e^{-Ht}\colon L^1\to L^2$ is bounded with the given operator norm.  It follows that the dual operator
$$\left(e^{-Ht}\right)^*\colon (L^2)^* \to (L^1)^*$$
is bounded with the same operator norm, because of the characterisation
$$\|T\|_{L^1\rightarrow L^2}=\|T^*\|_{L^\infty\rightarrow L^2}=\sup_{f,g}\frac{\langle Tf,g\rangle}{\|f\|_1\|g\|_2}\,.$$
Since $(L^1)^* = L^\infty$ and $(L^2)^* = L^2$ (these are isomorphisms, actually), it remains to check that $\left(e^{-Ht}\right)^* = e^{-Ht}$.

For this note that $$\int f(x)(e^{-Ht}g)(x)dx = \iint f(x)e(x,y;t)g(y)dxdy$$ where $e(x,y;t)$ is the heat kernel, which is real and symmetric in the variables $x,y$.  It follows that $\left(e^{-Ht}\right)^*$ is again integration against the heat kernel as claimed.

Comment: Thanks. your domain and range are mixed in the first line btw.

Comment: In the second line too.  Fixed now.

Comment: In the last step, all we really need is that the semigroup $e^{-Ht}$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator, which follows from the fact that $H$ is self-adjoint.  We don't need to use the fact that a heat kernel exists, which is quite a bit more difficult to prove.

Comment: This is not obvious to me.  I agree that $T=\exp(-Ht)\colon L^2\to L^2$ has $T^*=T$, but I don't see why that automatically shows something about the dual of $S=\exp(-Ht)\colon L^1\to L^2$.

Comment: @LiorSilberman or Nate: do you know how to prove that $(e^{-Ht})^* = e^{-Ht}$ using the weak formulation? It amounts to showing something like $(u(t),v(0))_{L^2} = (u(0),v(t))_{L^2}$, where $u$ and $v$ solutions of heat equation. I want to avoid this exponential representation

Comment: Basically you differentiate both sides wrt $t$ and use the self-adjointness of the Laplace operator, but this brushes asides various minor technical issues.

Comment: Does the second norm need correction, namely to make it as follows?

$$ \|T\|_{L^1\rightarrow L^2}=\|T^*\|_{L^2 \rightarrow L^\infty\}=\sup_{f,g}\frac{\langle Tf,g\rangle}{\|f\|_1\|g\|_2}\.$$